# Working on Git fork of inactive project

Tags: git, github

I am fairly new to Git and working on open source projects, in general. I've currently forked a repo of a project that does not seem to be actively maintained -- i.e., that last accepted PRs were close to a year ago, and changes before that were also sparse. I'd like to continue to work on this repo locally and also submit new features and bug fixes in the off chance that the maintainer comes back to check in on it.

So for instance, I created a bug fix branch, pushed it to my remote, then submitted a PR to the base of the fork. I went ahead and merged that bug fix in with a local dev branch which is my working copy of the code. My question is when I create subsequent feature branches with the intent of submitting them upstream, should they be branched from the upstream master (which is probably not subject to change anytime soon) or my dev branch which will have all of my new features and bug fixes?

[I found this Stack Exchange question that kind of touches on my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/214614/how-to-maintain-a-forked-git-repo-with-feature-branches-that-upstream-wont-pull), but is specific to when the upstream repo rejects the pull request and if you have no intention of merging local changes upstream. 
Ultimately: what is the best workflow for this kind of situation?

Hopefully that makes some sense. Thanks for your help

Comment: Change the upstream repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I create subsequent feature branches with the intent of submitting them upstream, should they be branched from the upstream master (which is probably not subject to change anytime soon) or my dev branch which will have all of my new features and bug fixes?

If the original upstream won't change, there is no point submitting it PR: you can make your feature branch:

- directly from origin/master: your fork
- or from a new upstream, meaning you create a new repo (mirror copy) of the original one, specifying clearly in the README this is a new start from an old repo.